# Why can an object be collected before its instance method finishing executing by GC in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, threadpoolexecutor

Running the following code, you might got an `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` exception.

```
/**
 * -Xmx20m -Xms20m
 *
 */
public class SingleThreadPoolTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
            newSingleThreadPool();
        }
    }

    private static void newSingleThreadPool() {
        // create a SingleThreadExecutor then submit a task to it
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 4];
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: exception]

The problem here is that the `SingleThreadExecutor` object could be GC collected which would execute its `finalize` so that the thread pool will be shutdown before its instance method `submit` finishing execute.

This seemed counterintuitive, it would produce bugs.
My question is, how could this happen? Is this a normal behavior of GC? And is there any other language with GC has the seem problem?

---

Here is a bug reported to the jdk bug system: [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(runnable) throws RejectedExecutionException](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145304)

Comment: Are your questions not answered by the discussion in the bug report? If not, what particularly?

Comment: @Kayaman The discussion focus on how this particularly problem occurs, why it was designed like this; this early collection seems to occur only when we use a thread. I wonder if it is a common problem of the languages that has a GC, and is there any possible solution to avoid such problems.

Comment: You do realize that this is a special case? They even mention the finalizer being added as almost like a "favor", because people weren't closing their executors properly. This also shows some dangers of finalization. Solutions or workarounds are discussed as well.

Comment: But according to JLS, the JVM is allowed to collect the object, so the issue is whether the JLS should be changed or whether programmers should be responsible for writing correct code. It's debatable which one is a bigger task ;)